# Error starting tabular SSAS instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, ssas-2012

I'm getting this message (on the log) when trying to start a SSAS Tabular Instance on SQL Server 2012. I already have a Multidimensional instance running so this would be a second one. I also tried with the default instance stopped but got the same error.

> Message: The service cannot be started: The following system error
>   occurred: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the
>   requested service.

I know the message seems obvious but its a DEV server with a lot of free resources (file size, CPU, RAM..)

Did anyone have this error before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this might seem obvious, but just to verify, did you install at least one instance in the tabular mode?  The interface (icons) do not always accurately reflect the mode - in particular the SQL Server Configuration Manager shows the icon for the UDM (OLAP) for any type of SSAS instance.

If you are certain that you did install a SSAS instance of type tabular, then are you able to verify (see) that instance in the SSCM?  If so, what is the service state, i.e. is it started?
If not, can you manually start the service there?  Does the service account have adequate permissions to run the service?

Give me a bit more information if none of these solutions work.